# How to create a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div inside a div. I want to create a div with a class of videos, inside the videos div. But it seems to not work.

````
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.class = "video";
    videosDiv.appendChild(div)const videosDiv = document.getElementById("videos");


    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.class = "video";
    videosDiv.appendChild(div)```
````

Comment: Please include the HTML part and [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what's the result and what's your expected.

Answer (score -3):

Use `const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("videos");` If you are filtering div elements by class `videos` and iterate the collection and append child with each element.